# Error on Paul Wilmott Section 5.2?

Tags: binomial, error

I gave this a long and hard thought because Paul Wilmott is a respected quant and I don't want to criticize his book, but am I correct in concluding that this section contains lots of errors? These are my observations and the specific section is at the bottom. I'm not trying to bash him, I'm just genuinely interested to master quantitative finance but couldn't get past this section because I think the calculations are wrong.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific where you think the errors are or even what you think would be correct? Thank you

Comment: I've attached the table of where I think he made mistakes, the corrections and the reason why.  I hope you can help correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't see that, I thought that this is a table from the book too. Thank you.

Comment: You are incorrect!  When you sell the stock as a hedge, you need to invest the proceeds at the risk free rate for one period.

Comment: But that is already imputed into the future expectation of the entire portfolio. The equation already found the PV of the entire portfolio value/gain.

Comment: Also,there is an associated cost with short borrows (repo/sbl fee) which usually is higher than the reinvestment rate,that should cancel it out at least and even make the PV smaller.

Comment: I will arb you as follows:  I buy from you one call for 0.4998, and I sell 0.5 stocks for proceeds of 50.  The net proceeds are 49.5002 which i invest for one day, obtaining 49.51984.   If the stock goes down, I need to buy it back for 49.5, obtaining 0.01984 profit.  If the stock goes up, I buy it back for 50.5 but I have 1 from the option payoff so it's the same result.  Certain profit of 0.01984.  The present value of that is the difference between your result and Wilmott.

Comment: But from that stand point,you're saying I'm allowed to borrow stock to sell free of charge and i'm also able to reinvest it at risk free rate..

Comment: Usually the you'll lift the offer to reinvest ( higher price of risk-free rate instrument at offer = lower yield) and hit the bid when borrowing (higher yield)

Comment: True- the theory assumes borrowing and lending at the same risk free rate- unattainable in practice.

Comment: I only looked for a min but don't understand your objections. Paul Wilmott is not infallible (no one is), but I have read his books and he is generally very careful. This text you're doubting is very basic, so the chances of Paul having messed this up are minimal imo. Now, if you are confident that "this chapter should be rewritten", you know there is the Wilmott forum, where you can repost this and get an answer from Paul himself. If you have the balls to do it and are prepared to be embarrassed:) By the way, you can focus on PDE methods instead as binomial trees are just a poor man's version

Comment: I've read your reasons again, and they make absolutely no sense. You seem very confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing from the very beginning,but how can the value of a portfolio have this formula: 1-101Δ? If Delta is calculated to be 1/2,then the value of the portfolio will be 1-50.5=-49.5?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found my error,thanks dm63 for the explanation.  I had a hard time imagining the negative position value and that it implies that I also get the interest from getting cash for the short..I used a slightly different approach  but got the same result.

FV when stock goes up = FV when stock goes down

1 -1Δ+100Δ(r)=1Δ+100Δ(r)

1 -1Δ=1Δ

Δ=.5

PV= FV/(1+r)

PV= (.5+50(.1/252))/(1+(.1/252))

PV= 0.5196

Thanks for all the help guys! 
Really appreciate it.

Comment: That's good. As an advice for the future, next time don't be so willing to believe that someone who is well known and respected has made a mistake in something that basic. This is arrogant if you don't mind me saying. I know because I did the exact same thing you did once a long time ago. But now I've learned better. Don't get me wrong, there are books out there with gross mistakes. But those usually get overwhelmingly bad reviews, which is not the case here. Good luck.

Comment: You're right..I didn't stop redoing the calculations because I know the probability of me being correct and wilmott being wrong is very slim. I deleted my comments before so as not to mislead readers of this thread. I just have a different way of learning and understanding things but that doesn't make other people's approach incorrect. :)